# Phonegap Internet Connection redirect

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Hi i'm currently working on a redirect if the user dont have a internet connection

Sample Code to alert the connection

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

So i changed it to

```
function InternetOK(){
        var networkState =navigator.connection.type
        var states = {};
        if (state == "NONE" ){
           window.location = "offline.html";
            }
        }
```

This Code is in index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="iamstupid">
  <a href="news.html" onClick="InternetOK();">News</a>
.
.
.
```

Something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

function checkConnection(){
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

```
   if (networkState == Connection.NONE ){
   window.location = "offline.html";
   }
```

}